# How to inject module on click of button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have one directive like following

```
var directiveApp = angular.module("directiveApp", ['ngSanitize', 'ui.mask', 'ngCropper', 'ui.bootstrap', 'common.fabric', 'common.fabric.utilities', 'common.fabric.constants', 'ui.sortable', 'ui.select']);
```

Also, this is an external directive js file and want to inject this on click of a button.

I have tried to include this js file through javascript but does not find a way to inject it in the controller. As I am injecting before including this file I am getting the js errors.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

Comment: Thank you so much! It had fixed my problem!